# Detect keyCode issue wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I need to detect when user select on keyboard letter `]` KeyCode: 221 and return the letter `]` on the dom.

My problem is:

The value returned by `event.keyCode` is different if the event is returned from an `input` element or `document`.

Also

testing the following issue on Chrome Version 55.0

I get for input:
event.keyCode: 93 - String.fromCharCode: ]

I get for document:
event.keyCode: 221 - String.fromCharCode: Ý

and on Firefox 50.1.0

I get for input:
event.keyCode: 0 - String.fromCharCode:

I get for document:
event.keyCode: 221 - String.fromCharCode: Ý

I would need to know:

- What is wrong with my code?
- What is a consistent way to have the same value?

Notes: I am using a ENG United State international keyboard (could this be relevant?).

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
input.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  result.innerHTML = `event.keyCode: ${event.keyCode} - String.fromCharCode: ${String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)}`;

});

var resultDocument = document.getElementById('resultDocument');

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  resultDocument.innerHTML = `event.keyCode: ${event.keyCode} - String.fromCharCode: ${String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)}`;
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" size="40">
<div id="result"></div>

<h1>On document</h1>
<div id="resultDocument"></div>
```

Comment: This is because to get that character, you need to press either `fn`+`option`+`9` on a Mac, and `AltGr`+`9`(If I remember correctly) on a computer. The `Fn`,`option` and `AltGr` isn't registered as keypresses in javascript, as far as I remember. Unfortunately, I cannot provide a distinct way of getting the value this instant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event.keyCode is deprecated and [inconsistent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) across browsers, use Event.key instead if available. If not, your best bet would be to use a library such as [Keypress](https://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/). jQuery will also do.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine, it seems (at least it gives the same answer in Firefox, haven't tested in other browsers)

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
input.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  result.innerHTML = `event.which: ${event.which} - String.fromCharCode: ${String.fromCharCode(event.which)}`;
});

var resultDocument = document.getElementById('resultDocument');

document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
  resultDocument.innerHTML = `event.which: ${event.which} - String.fromCharCode: ${String.fromCharCode(event.which)}`;
});
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" size="40">
<div id="result"></div>

<h1>On document</h1>
<div id="resultDocument"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using keypress event for getting keycode from input and keydown from document. Keyup and Keydown always returns the unicode value of the uppercase version of a character. So if if you want it to be case sensitive, I recommend to use Keyup, otherwise you can use keypress.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/eventkeyboardmouse.shtml
Check it out for more info. Cheers